# Designing stratified random sampling considering two or more shapefiles in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sampling, stratified-sampling

I have two different shapefiles, one containing field boundaries other is a soil class. I want to choose stratified random sampling points (around 200 points) which will be representative of both fields and soil type.
Can anybody suggest how to do it in QGIS?

[image]

Comment: Please decide which software you want to work with. What research have you done on random points?

Comment: I would prefer QGIS and the sampling points are necessary to decide our filed sampling for some soil nutrient analysis.

Comment: Let me rephrase: What research have you done on how to create and select random points?

Comment: Asking how to do something in two very different software stacks, violates the One question per Question policy emphasized by the [Tour]. If you've chosen QGIS, you now need to [Edit] the Question to focus on what you have attempted with QGIS, and what difficulty you've encountered.

Comment: @Vince, Thanks for editing my question, It would be nice if you could help me solving the problem.